# Unable To Fetch Records From SQL Table To DataGridView In C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a windows form where the user can input multiple values in multiple textboxes for faster search results. But when running, it takes only 1st parameter i.e., the fullname and ignores the other. Don't know the reason why is it so.
Am getting the full table in the result which I don't want.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MADDY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ContactName LIKE '%" + txtFullName.Text + "%' OR Address LIKE '%" + txtAddress.Text + " %' OR Phone LIKE '%"+txtContactNumber.Text+"%'";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataTable ds = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(ds);
         if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
     }
 }
```

Where am I making mistake, please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Checked. No result yet. Any other option ?

Comment: Are you entering text in all the textboxes? If you miss anyone, the query condition statement would have this expression `OR Address  LIKE '%%'`, which would result into all records being selected at the output

Comment: @DipenduPaul how to avoid that ? what if user inputs just the name and wants the result of that name or similar to that name only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when a user leaves a textbox empty, she doesn't want the condition the textbox entry corresponds to, be included and that's where it seems the current one going wrong. But this is an assumption and needs to verified by you.

So in my opinion the query should be built like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers "
string condition = String.Empty;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFullName.Text))
  condition  += "WHERE ContactName LIKE '%" + txtFullName.Text + "%' "

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
     condition  += "OR Address LIKE '%" + txtAddress.Text + " %' "
  else
     condition  += "WHERE Address LIKE '%" + txtAddress.Text + " %' " 

//and so on....


sql = sql + condition;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
```

Also, I hope you won't forget to add a  dataGridView1.Databind() statement. Let me know if this observation was correct.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it with stored procedure ? I'll be grateful if you do so.

Comment: Yes sure. I would suggest you to start it as another question. That way your question would get attention of other members. Share the question link with me and I will chip in too.

Comment: check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112974/unable-to-fetch-records-from-sql-table-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp-using-stored-p

Comment: sorry for catching up late. I have added my solution to your post. In case you are still looking for a solution, please have a look at it. And let me know if it worked for you.